# How do I get a series of IEnumerable object to look like one big stackpanel in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, stackpanel

I have, for this example, an IList<> that contains a set of objects that are also lists.  for example, a league consists of a set of teams and those teams are comprised of players.  What I want is a single list that has one scrollbar.

I have tried nested ListBox controls but that ends up being a stack of multiple scrollbars that acts horrible.  Scrolling is just bad and it seems to hide the bottom of the team's player list.

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a `ListBox`, why not use an `ItemsControl`? A `ListBox` provides selection, if you do not need this, an `ItemsControl` is [more lightweight and will load faster](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/02/windows-phone-7-performance-measurements-emulator-vs-hardware/). Also, with an `ItemsControl` you have full control over the elements that host your items. This way, you can omit the `ScrollViewer`.

To render your items, try the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding League.Teams}>
  <!-- use a StackPanel to host your elements -->
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <!-- render each team -->
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- render each player within the team -->
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding Players}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <!-- render the player's name -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I don't know why SO is not syntax highlighting my XAML :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can disable scrollbars for a ListBox quite easily. Just add `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` to the XAML attributes for the inner ListBox.